# Android theme inheritance

Tags: android, inheritance, themes

I have a base theme and a derived theme, how can i change the custom styles in the inherited theme?

What i'm curreently trying:

This is my Button

```
<Button
    style="globalButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

These are the Styles

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="globalButtonStyle">@style/myCoolButtonStyle1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCoolAppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="globalButtonStyle">@style/myCoolButtonStyle1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myCoolButtonStyle1">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myCoolButtonStyle2">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

How can i use "globalButtonStyle" as style for my button?

Background is that i want to brand the app different for multiple customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your custom attribute

```
<resources>
   <attr name="globalButtonStyle" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

styles.xml is same

your button declaration will be next

```
<Button
    style="?attr/globalButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: i dont want to override all buttons

Comment: @wutzebaer see my update according your clarificaiton

Comment: I will do that via productFlavor, but it's only when you familiar with that, see http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html